# Reciprocal of Gamma function for negative integers

Tags: gamma-function

On page 255 of  the book "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" by Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun, it is mentioned that

$$\lim_{z \to n} \frac{1}{\Gamma{(-z)}}=0=\frac{1}{(-n-1)!}.$$

I am not able to understand why it is equal to $\frac{1}{(-n-1)!}$.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It equals that because $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ is how we extend the factorial function. It is by definition.
Just like $(1/2)!$ and other numbers are, by definition, defined by the Gamma function.

The limit is a property of the Gamma function, I suppose.

Comment: The values $\Gamma(0)$, $\Gamma(-1)$, $\Gamma(-2)$, and so on, are all $\infty$. If you use the extension of factorial mentioned by the comment above, it would correspond to taking $(-1)!=\infty$, $(-2)!=\infty$, $(-3)!=\infty$, and so on. But it may be seen as abuse of notation. But do not that [the reciprocal gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function) $1/\Gamma$ is defined (finite) in every point; in fact an _entire_ function.